# Observation numbers (n) in one line at the bottom of a percentage barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are many similar questions, but I couldn’t find an answer to my question. The observation numbers of each group and each day should be written at the bottom (!) of the percentage barplot like in this example.

[image]

I don't know how I could do this.

My dataframe:

```
  day cohort  n  mean    se  
1   1 CLOSED 70 47.66 26.63
2   2 CLOSED 70 60.19 23.72
3   3 CLOSED 67 65.68 23.16
4   4 CLOSED 60 67.96 21.38
5   1   OPEN 66 31.45 31.59
6   2   OPEN 66 39.83 25.76
7   3   OPEN 61 38.53 24.06
8   3   OPEN 52 45.23 25.00
....
```

My code:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = day, y = mean, fill = cohort))

p2 + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
              color = "black",
              position = position_dodge(0.9),
              size = 1) +
     geom_text(aes(label = n),
               color = "black",
               size = 3.5,
               position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
               vjust = 1.5) +
     labs(x = "Day",
          y = "Time in target range (%)")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix `y value` for `geom_text`

here is an example.

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:5,],aes(rownames(mtcars[1:5,]),qsec,label=qsec))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="white",colour="black")+ 
    geom_text(aes(label=qsec,y=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours to find a solution. Only y=4 in aes() was the missing part.

Comment: There is also vjust (outside aes) for example putting y=0 in aes `geom_text(aes(label=qsec,y=0), vjust=-5)`. Eventhough you had it in your example, I think this is not dependent on the scale this way so it would be better than putting directly 4 (?).  And there is also nudge_y which seems to be scale dependent also thus not so useful.